# Forbidden error with WPS process chaining

Tags: geoserver, wps

We have published some geo-processing map services (it’s called WPS in OGC terms) in ArcGIS Server. So I have looked into GeoServer to see if we can do the same. I’ve found following issues. Not sure if it’s related to “HTTP” protocol.

1. When tested “Process Chaining”, got 403 error. To reproduce the issue, follow the steps below:
   -Go to the Demo WPS Request Builder interface, and select gs:Clip from the first combo-box Select the Vector Layer sf:streams as input.
   -For the clip input select SUBPROCESS and then click on Define/edit. Another WPS Builder dialog window should appear, but got 403 error
2. When tested WPS “Execute process”, got “308 Permanent Redirect” response. To reproduce this issue, follow the steps below:

-Go to the Demo WPS Request Builder interface, and select JTS:intersection from the first combo-box.

-The interface asks for two mandatory parameters, a and b, which must be geometries. Choose application/WKT for all input and output parameters and insert the following inputs for a and be:

```
        a --> POLYGON((0 0, 0 10, 10 10, 10 0, 0 0))

        b --> POLYGON((5 5, 5 15, 15 15, 15 5, 5 5))
```

-Click on Execute Process after having selected application/WKT as type of the generated result, we expect to get back a polygon representing the intersection between a and b which should be:
POLYGON ((5 10, 10 10, 10 5, 5 5, 5 10))

Instead, 308 Permannent Redirect response is returned.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Don't post pictures of text - it is hard for everyone (including google) to read and makes it much harder to answer your question

Comment: Thanks. I have updated my question to provide text information instead.